# ExtJS window animations with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, extjs

I need to achieve the following effect with jQuery:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/desktop/desktop.html

Clicking on the "Grid Window" or "Accordion Window" icons will open windows in "zooming" manner from left bottom corner to the middle of the page.

What I need to do is - do the same with jQuery but to move the opening window to the right bottom position of the page.

Could anybody tell me on how that can be achieved or if there's already a jQuery plugin for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One first step can be to use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to update the `top, left, width, height` properties of your window :

```
// compute target x,y coordinates of the bottom right corner
$('#window').animate({
    top: target.top,
    left: target.left,
    width: 0,
    height: 0
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cB9K/)

Comment: That will update all those properties at once. My understanding is that ExtJs updates those properties in parallel which makes that animation.

Comment: Added a fiddle. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I understood your question as "I need to close the window towards the bottom right". This can be changed by adjusting the values of `top, left, width, height`

Comment: I actually did not want to close it but understood already how that can be done. Thank you!